# How to parse Json with jquery having special chars in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got a json structure somehow as below and my question is how can i parse this with jQuery so that i can use it like `myJson[0].name` and than alert it so that `"M\\xe9t\\xe9o" = Météo`.

Jquery tells me this is invalid json why ?
Json uses double backslash if i use single backslash ("M\xe9t\xe9o") Jquery is OK with the syntax.

```
var jsonObj = '{"title":[{"id":"1","name": "M\\xe9t\\xe9o"},{"id":"2","name": "Meteo"}]}';

var myJson = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSON syntax](http://json.org) only [allows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#page-5) `\uxxxx` escapes.
Change it to `"M\\u00e9t\\u00e9o"`.

If you use a single backslash, it gets parsed by the Javascript string literal, so the actual string value contains the real Unicode character, not an escape.  In other words, `"M\xe9t\xe9o" === "Météo"`

Comment: my bad i assumed it accepted \\x i'll change it to \\uxxxx looks like it works thx

Answer (score 0):

It is looks like the json was incorrectly (manually?) encoded. When you encode it in UTF-8, e.g. with PHP, you'll get:

```
{"title":[{"id":"1","name": "M\u00e9t\u00e9o"},{"id":"2","name": "Meteo"}]}
```

which is correctly parsed by JS. But `\xe9` is unrecognized by parser.